# Split a column of strings (with different patterns) based on two different conditions

Tags: r, string, data-manipulation, strsplit

Was hoping to get some help with this problem. So I have a column with two types of strings and I would need to split the strings into multiple columns using 2 different conditions. I can figure out how to split them individually but struggling to add maybe an IF statement to my code. This is the example dataset below:

```
data = data.frame(string=c("HFUFN-087836_661", "207465-125 - IK_6 Mar 2009.docx_37484956"))
```

For the first type of variable (with the _). I would like to split after the _. So I used the following code for that

```
strsplit(data$string, "-")
```

For variables that have.docx in them I would like to split after the docx. I cannot split based on "_" as it comes multiple times in this string. So I used the following code:

```
strsplit(data$string, "x_")
```

My question is both these types of strings appear in the same column. Is there a way to tell R if "docx" is in the string then split after x_, but if its not split on the _?

Any help would be appreciated - Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `tidyr` solution:

```
library(tidyr)
data %>%
extract(string,
        into = c("1","2"),    # choose your own column labels
        "(.*?)_([^_]+)$")
                                1        2
1                    HFUFN-087836      661
2 207465-125 - IK_6 Mar 2009.docx 37484956
```

**How the regex works**:

The regex partitions the strings into two "capture groups" plus an underscore in-between:

- `(.*?)`: first capture group, matching any character (`.`) zero or more times (`*`) non-greedily (`?`)
- `_`: a literal underscore
- `([^_]+)$`: the second capture group, matching any character that is **not** an underscore (`[^_]`) one or more times (`+`) at the very end of he string (`$`)

Data:

```
data = data.frame(string=c("HFUFN-087836_661", "207465-125 - IK_6 Mar 2009.docx_37484956"))
```

Comment: Hey this worked - thank you so much. If its not too much work can you please explain how you did this? I don't quite get this part: " "(.*?)_([^_]+)$")". Thanks so much!

Comment: Have provided an explanation of how th regex part works